# Deployed project cannot load the default document and lists the directory instead

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

Below are my project specifications :

- ASP.NET MVC 5
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- IIS 8.5

I deployed my project on a server composed of above specifications. Now, When I try to load the project, it lists the directory of my project instead of loading the default document as below :

[image]

What could possibly be the thing I'm doing wrong here? Why is it not loading the initial page of the application?

Comment: is the application pool using Integrated pipeline mode?

Comment: @adiga Absolutely, Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out, goes this way :

- Click "Server Manager"
- Click "Manage" at the top right
- Go to "Add Roles and Features"
- Proceed until "Server Roles"
- In the "Server Roles" tab of the "Roles" section Check "Web Server (IIS)" > "Web Server" > "Application Development" > Check all except "CGI"
- Click "Next" & "Install"

You are good to go.